# How can I configure Android so that all Internet traffic goes through a VPN and is blocked if the VPN isn't activated, without rooting Android?

Tags: security, privacy, internet, vpn, android-10

How can I configure Android so that all Internet traffic goes through a VPN and is blocked if the VPN isn't activated, without rooting Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [Always-on](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/vpn#always-on) VPN, which is a stock feature since Android 7 (root not needed). You will see the "Always-on" & “Block connections without VPN", options in VPN settings.

If you are looking to have this feature on pre-Andoid 7 devices, you need to look for VPN apps that offer this. For example, this [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.simplexsolutionsinc.vpn_unlimited) offers this feature by name of "Kill Switch"

---

On Android 10 with AnyConnect VPN: Settings → Connections  → More connection
settings   → Select the VPN client  → Enable "Always-on VPN" and "Block connections without VPN":

[image]